# NiFi: best flow to insert data from Kafka to Cassandra?

Tags: apache-nifi

I spent 2 days on my research and now I need you guys help. Thank you in advance.

I have following flow:
1) ConsumeKafka (messages are in JSON format)
2) EvaluateJsonPath
3) UpdateAttributes
4) AttributesToJson

All above flow is working but following rest of flow is not working:
5) PutCassandraRecord (I need help on how to configure this processor. I know my Cassandra server, port, keyspace, table name, record reader is JsonPathReader). What else???
6) added controller service - JsonPathReader (here I need help as to how this record reader must be configured). 
7) I am getting exception as attached file below. Where and how to I get or configure Schema Registry?
[image]

I checked this question and answer: [Apache Nifi/Cassandra - how to load CSV into Cassandra table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39201597/apache-nifi-cassandra-how-to-load-csv-into-cassandra-table)

Guys if my flow is wrong please correct me. Thanks.

regards,
Yeshwant

Comment: Does your flow file have an attribute named valor.vaengine ?

Comment: Hi Bryan, Valor indicates keyspace name of Cassandra. And 'vaengine' is name of the table. In my JSON file there is no attribute related to this keyspace and table name.

Comment: When you use ${something} that is an expression language statement referencing a flow file attribute named 'something'. Flow file attributes are different than the content of the flow file, so something would need to create the attribute valor.vaengine as Shu mentioned in his answer

Comment: Thank you Bryan for clearing my concepts.

Answer (score 1):

There are `multiple ways` we can configure **Record Reader/writer** controller service

i will try to explain the below two **Schema Access Strategy**

- Use 'Schema Name' Property
- Use 'Schema Text' Property

***Use SchemaText property:***

In this access strategy processor will look for `avro.schema` attribute in VariableRegistry/FlowfileAttributes (or) we can give `schema in the property value`.

**Example:**

I have given schema text property value as my avro schema
[image]

***Use 'Schema Name' Property:***

[image]

In this strategy processor checks `Schema Name` property value `${valor.vaengine}` (it's an attribute name) so we need to have value for this **attribute associated** with the flowfile.

Then controller service uses `${valor.vaengine}` value uses appropriate schema from `AvroSchemaRegistry` that has been used by this controller service.

In your case your **flowfile** not having `${valor.vaengine}` attribute, to add this attribute to the flowfile use `UpdateAttribute` processor add new property as

**valor.vaengine**

```
<schema_name_in_avroschemaregistry>
```

Use [this](https://github.com/shureddy/NiFiTemplates/blob/master/SchemaAcess_Strategies.xml) template for more details regards to configuring/usage of `Record Reader/writer` Controller services

---

You are using [JsonPathReader](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-record-serialization-services-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.json.JsonPathReader/additionalDetails.html) controller service for this controller service

we need to add **atleast one user defined properties** to enable the controller service, like property name as *`id`* value as `$.id`

Comment: Dear Shu thank you so much. I will grasp and try out your solution and get back to you. Thanks.